Can I connect to SQL Sever 2022 from Java 1.7 Legacy Application?
I have a legacy application that is running on Java 1.7. And I need to connect to Microsoft SQL Server 2022. When I do this, I am getting an exception of
Caused by: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: SQL Server did not return a response. The connection has been closed..)

If I read the documentation correctly, I need a JDK version of minimum 1.8 to upgrade the JDBC driver that supports SQL Server 2022. Is there any workaround for this?

Why can't you upgrade to a more recent version of Java? 1.7 is EOL. In fact it has not had any security updates for years and therefore anyone still using 1.7 could be deemed reckless. If your employer won't let you upgrade, find another employer.

What driver and version are you using and how does your connection string look?

According to the Support Matrix, the only [JDBC] driver versions compatible with SQL Server 2022 are 12.2, 12.4 and 12.6. According to the Release Notes all those versions are compatible with JDK 8 and above. So, as Jake Blues said to the Penguin in the movie "The Blues Brothers": I guess you're up sh*t creek :-)

@siggemannen Currently 4.3.11 Microsoft JDBC Driver.
Connection string looks like this. jdbc:sqlserver://database;databaseName=db_name;sendStringParametersAsUnicode=false;encrypt=false;integratedSecurity=true;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true

Why do you have both encrypt false and true. Try just: false

There's no problem using older drivers for sql server 2022 @Abra, at least i've been using 9.1 for sql server 2022 without any issues, of course not everything might work

@user10872969 i think you should look into upgrading to 1.8 anyway, java 1.7 was a failure and is slow, while 1.8 just works (tm).

@siggemannen Sorry, that was a mistake on my part when I copied the string. I tried both with 'encrypt=true' and 'encrypt=false', but neither is working.

You might need to upgrade as far as JDBC Driver 6.4 for SQL Server: it's the first one that adds support for the sslProtocol=TLSv1.2; connection string property while being the last one that maintains compatibility with JRE 1.7. ("Officially" you need v12.2 to connect to SQL Server 2022, though.)

I tried using 6.1.jre7 driver against my own sql server 2022 and it worked just fine. Wonder if the problem with the ssl stuff in java7 itself, since i couldn't find access to a real java 7 environment and run against java 1.8
